# Remove double join results from query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query where I join a table on itself to find mismatches between a parts height or width. The only problem is that because of this join it will return each miss-match twice for each part. I only want to return one row for each miss-match, not two.

Here's the table:

```
tblTagGlass
JobID varchar
UnitCode varchar
PartCode varchar
PartQty int
TagHeight float
TagWidth float
```

and the query:

```
select *
from tblTagGlass ttg
inner join tblTagGlass ttgC ON
ttg.JobID = ttgC.JobID
AND ttg.PartCode = ttgC.PartCode
where ttg.TagHeight != ttgC.TagHeight
or ttg.TagWidth != ttgC.TagWidth
order by ttg.PartCode
```

and the results:

```
INC375 U2-052 VT2-011 1 2013   1444.5   INC375 U2-028 VT2-011 1 2012.5 1444.5
INC375 U2-028 VT2-011 1 2012.5 1444.5   INC375 U2-052 VT2-011 1 2013   1444.5
```

I hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select *
from tblTagGlass ttg
inner join tblTagGlass ttgC ON
ttg.JobID = ttgC.JobID
AND ttg.PartCode = ttgC.PartCode
where (ttg.TagHeight != ttgC.TagHeight OR ttg.TagWidth != ttgC.TagWidth)
AND ((ttg.TagHeight >= ttgC.TagHeight AND ttg.TagWidth >= ttgC.TagWidth) 
    OR (ttg.TagHeight > ttgC.TagHeight AND ttg.TagWidth < ttgC.TagWidth))
order by ttg.PartCode
```

The difference is using > to compare them instead of !=

Comment: Works well in that case, yes.  However, in other cases, it won't - such as if the heights aren't equal.  So the quick solution is to make that a ">" also.  But then, if height is greater on one row, but width is lesser - you'll be right back where you started.  See my answer for a solution.

Comment: As far as I understand the problem it will still work,

an example (In SQL server syntax)
Both Keyvals 4 and 5 are returned which have both valA and valB different

Comment: create table Test(PK int identity(1,1), KeyVal int, valA int, valB int)

    insert into Test values (1, 1, 1)
    insert into Test values (1, 1, 1)
    insert into Test values (2, 1, 1)
    insert into Test values (2, 2, 1)
    insert into Test values (3, 1, 2)
    insert into Test values (3, 1, 1)
    insert into Test values (4, 1, 2)
    insert into Test values (4, 2, 1)
    insert into Test values (5, 2, 1)
    insert into Test values (5, 1, 2)

    select * 
    from Test A
    join Test B
    on A.valA <> B.valA
    and A.valB > B.valB
    and A.KeyVal = B.KeyVal

Comment: @Tetraneutron - he's looking for the part which has width OR height different.  your SQL has an AND in the join.  Change that to an OR.

Comment: I think its right, The check to see if they are different has an OR in it, then to restrict it to one row per difference it checks that the first table is >= the second for both columns (which by the previous check at least one column will be) - Of course as stated below if you have some key field (say a candidate key (unique) that is comparable with > you could use that (as the only greater than comparison (in which case you wouldn't use >=))

Answer (score 1):

Let's make an assumption:

- PRIMARY KEY(JobCode, UnitCode, PartCode)

What you are looking for is items with the same JobCode and PartCode but with different UnitCode values - and with a difference in either the TagHeight or TagWidth (or both).  So, use the '>' trick on UnitCode to distinguish between rows and prevent duplicates, but '!=' to detect the differences in TagHeight or TagWidth:

```
SELECT *
    FROM tblTagGlass ttg JOIN tblTagGlass ttgC
         ON  ttg.JobID = ttgC.JobID
         AND ttg.PartCode = ttgC.PartCode
         AND ttg.UnitCode > ttgC.UnitCode
    WHERE (ttg.TagHeight != ttgC.TagHeight
       OR ttg.TagWidth != ttgC.TagWidth)
    ORDER BY ttg.PartCode
```

Answer (score -1):

The question becomes, which information do you want from the rows.  They are different rows.

If you just want the part code, this will work:

```
select ttg.PartCode
from tblTagGlass ttg
inner join tblTagGlass ttgC ON
ttg.JobID = ttgC.JobID
AND ttg.PartCode = ttgC.PartCode
where ttg.TagHeight != ttgC.TagHeight
or ttg.TagWidth != ttgC.TagWidth
group by ttg.PartCode
order by ttg.PartCode
```

Aside from that, you'll need to decide what aggregation of information you want across the rows.

Comment: I want the UnitCode, PartCode, Height, and Width the mismatches

Comment: if they are mismatches, which Height/Width do you want?  Your logic is a bit flawed...

Comment: love getting down voted for providing the correct answer.  God bless SO.  lol